# Trouble establishing a has_and_belongs_to_many relationship in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have tried every possible suggestion I could find on here to make this work but still can't get it to happen.

I have two models: districts and former_offices -- a district can have many former offices and a former office has a district.
Districts:

```
class District < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :former_office
end
```

Former Office:

```
class FormerOffice < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :districts
end
```

Join Model:

```
class DistrictFormerOffice < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :district
  belongs_to :former_office
end
```

Here is my form setup for creating a new former office:

```
<%= bootstrap_form_for(@former_office, label_errors: true) do |f| %>
   <%= f.select(:district_ids, District.all.collect { |v| ["#{v.jurisdiction.name} - #{v.name} (District #{v.district}) #{v.term_expires}", v.id ] }, { :include_blank => true}) %></div>
<% end %>
```

Former Offices controller:

```
def former_office_params
  params.require(:former_office).permit(district_ids: [])
end
```

Migration:

```
class CreateJoinTableDistrictFormerOffices < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :districts_former_offices, id: false do |t|
      t.bigint :district_id
      t.bigint :former_office_id
    end

    add_index :districts_former_offices, :district_id
    add_index :districts_former_offices, :former_office_id
  end
end
```

I am able to create the Former Office without any errors. All the other fields populate just find, except for "districts." When I pull up the object in the console and type former_office.districts, it comes up as "nil." So it appears either data isn't being added to the database, or is added in the wrong manner.

In the views, if I set it to display @former_office.districts, it just shows up blank.

Let me know if you need further information from my end. I sense this is an easy fix...but just can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can add "district_ids" directly into your FormerOffice model. Instead you need to load all the districts from the district model, like `@districts = District.find(former_office[:district_ids))`, and then do something like @former_office.districts = @districts